# How to create datasource with observable model?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, observablecollection

I have the grid with checkboxes with local data source.

I would like checked\uncheked a row (without visual effect) and I would like save state checkboxes for pager.

example:
If I uncheck first record on first page and will go to second page and return to first page first record MUST BE uncheck.

How to do this?

I trying

```
 var gridModel = kendo.observable({
        gridData: dataSource
    });
kendo.bind($("#chart"),gridModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dude_jsfiddle/Pf3TQ/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings are not supported inside of the client template - you can only use client expressions like #= #, #: #, # #.

Basically what you are looking for is discussed in a code library. Anyway I updated the JsBin with extra logic that demonstrates what you search for:

```
 template: '<input type="checkbox" #= IsSelected ? "checked" : ""#  "></input>',
```

And the most vital logic that actually updates the underlying model:

```
grid.tbody.on('click',':checkbox',function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    grid.dataItem(tr).set('IsSelected',$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pf3TQ/26/).

Comment: it's not observable. I need data bind

Comment: I wnat that http://jsfiddle.net/dude_jsfiddle/FZdhy/1/ but it template I need in grid